# Mesh with particles not rendering after append from 2.79 to 2.80

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I have a keyframed mesh (shape keys) with particle system created in Blender 2.8. I need to finish the project in 2.79 so the only way to import this mesh with particles is to append it as an object.

In 2.79 everything works except that the appended mesh is not rendering. It is transparent. Particles are working just fine.

After removing particles the mesh is renderable again.
Is there a solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after a couple of hours trying to figure this out and just after posting this question I have found the answer. Emitter has to be checked in particles Render settings. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 2.8 it is almost the same as you said Mikez: go to ***Context.Particles*** panel and under ***Render*** you can see a checkbox that says *"Show Emitter"*.